# Trying to Install HP-HEALTH for Proliant DL585N G5 on Debian Bullseye

Tags: linux, debian, hp, packages

I'm building a small personal server room with some older servers and exploring running new tools like proxmox.

One such machine is an HP ProLiant DL585 G5, Quad Opteron with 40GB DDR2 that I would like to create a virtualization server with proxmox. That said, I installed Debian 11 and now I'm trying to configure the old HP-HEALTH to be able to automate the reading of the machine's sensors.

But since this app has been discontinued, I'm having trouble installing it. I can find the .deb package, but when I try to install:

```
 hp-health depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.7-1); however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 hp-health depends on libc6-i686 | lib32gcc1; however:
  Package libc6-i686 is not installed.
  Package lib32gcc1 is not installed.
```

Does anyone know of a way to install this dependencies?

> And just to clarify... I'm a collector of old computers and the
> challenge here is really to build a small "datacenter" with old
> machines.. So please, don't tell me to put a newer machine...

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to follow the guid for installing the Management Component Pack (MCP) for your Debian 11 system.

https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/mcp/

> Subscribe Deb-based systems to the mcp repository Cut-n-paste the
> following section (substituting distribution, architecture and project
> version) into /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mcp.list on your system:
>
> **HPE Management Component Pack  deb**
>
> Where:    dist             jammy, bullseye, focal, buster, bionic,
> xenial, precise, stretch, jessie    project_ver      current, 12.40,
> 12.30, 12.20, 12.05, 12.00, 11.30, 11.21, 11.05
> Install the HPE public gpg key
>
> http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/keys
>
> Update the local apt indexes
>
> ```
> apt-get update
> ```
>
> Search for a specific package
>
> ```
> apt-cache search <packagename> # browse debs
> ```
>
> Install a specific package
>
> ```
> apt-get install <packagename>http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp dist/project_ver non-free
> ```